# Change values of a column based on the previous row using assign and a variable passed as a parameter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

Let it be the following Python Panda Dataframe:

| code | visit_time | flag | other | counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 0 | 1 days 03:00:12 | False | Y | 1 |
| 0 | NaT | False | X | 3 |
| 0 | 0 days 05:00:00 | True | X | 2 |
| 1 | NaT | False | Z | 3 |
| 1 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 1 | 1 days 03:00:12 | False | Y | 1 |
| 2 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 2 | 5 days 10:01:12 | True | Y | 0 |

To solve the problem, only the columns: `code, visit_time` and `flag` are needed.

Each row with a value of `visit_time`, has a previous row with value `NaT`. Knowing this, I want to do next modification in the dataframe:

- Sets the flag of the row with non-null value of `visit_time` to the same value as its previous row.

Code used @Cameron Riddell:

```
out = df.assign(
    flag=df['flag'].mask(df['visit_time'].notnull(), df['flag'].shift())
)

print(out)
   code      visit_time   flag other  counter
0     0             NaT   True     X        3
1     0 1 days 03:00:12   True     Y        1
2     0             NaT  False     X        3
3     0 0 days 05:00:00  False     X        2
4     1             NaT  False     Z        3
5     1             NaT   True     X        3
6     1 1 days 03:00:12   True     Y        1
7     2             NaT   True     X        3
8     2 5 days 10:01:12   True     Y        0
```

The problem is that I want to reuse the code in a function, so the `flag` column will be stored in a variable, say `name`. If I use the following code, a new column `name` is created in the DataFrame.

```
name = 'flag'
out = df.assign(
    name=df[name].mask(df['visit_time'].notnull(), df[name].shift())
)
```

How could I get the same functionality but being able to modify the values of the column passed by parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `**` for unpacks dictionary into keyword arguments:

```
name = 'flag'
out = df.assign(**{name: df[name].mask(df['visit_time'].notnull(), df[name].shift())})
```